# why spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto set update but schema.sql and data.sql still executing?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I use schema.sql and data.sql at developing step, but I need to release a version to the server, so I modify the ddl-auto=none to  ddl-auto=update, But after I re-execute, schema.sql and data.sql are still executed, why?

there's my config:

```
server:
 port: 8081

spring:
 jpa:
  hibernate:
   ddl-auto: update
 show-sql: true
 database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect


 profiles:
  active: prod
```

and here is my log:

```css
2020-05-26 12:57:49.412  INFO 3642 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/Users/shawnwu4mac/IdeaProjects/UTM-system-LSTM/target/classes/schema.sql]
2020-05-26 12:57:52.587  INFO 3642 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/Users/shawnwu4mac/IdeaProjects/UTM-system-LSTM/target/classes/schema.sql] in 3175 ms.
2020-05-26 12:57:52.592  INFO 3642 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/Users/shawnwu4mac/IdeaProjects/UTM-system-LSTM/target/classes/data.sql]
2020-05-26 12:57:53.785  INFO 3642 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/Users/shawnwu4mac/IdeaProjects/UTM-system-LSTM/target/classes/data.sql] in 1193 ms.
2020-05-26 12:57:53.962  INFO 3642 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-26 12:57:53.972  INFO 3642 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: default
 ...]
2020-05-26 12:57:54.028  INFO 3642 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2020-05-26 12:57:54.029  INFO 3642 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-05-26 12:57:54.030  INFO 3642 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2020-05-26 12:57:54.060  INFO 3642 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2020-05-26 12:57:54.137  INFO 3642 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-05-26 12:57:54.527  INFO 3642 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2020-05-26 12:58:00.756  INFO 3642 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Please do not use images to post code or logs. Use text formatted as code instead.

Comment: Because they are different mechanisms. Neither of which you shoud use in production. Instead use something like flyway or liquibase to manage your db schema.

Comment: So shouldn't I use schema.sql in a release environment?

Answer (score 0):

you must also add below property for your yml. it works well for me.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
```